# Edit bibliography style of bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to edit the bibliography style in the references when using `bibtex`. I would like to edit so that articles in the references appears as:

> Tenn Raa, T., Chakraborty, D. and Small, J. 1984. “An Alternative Treatment of
>   Secondary Products in Input-Output Analysis”. Review of Economics and Estatics. 66
>   (1): 88-97.

I don't know how to modified so that year appears without parenthesis, title with quotation marks, and volume, issue and pages as it appear in the example.

Comment: Moat importantly here, we need to know what BibTeX style you are using: what is the argument to `\bibliographystyle`?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,openbib]{article}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{apalike}
.....

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblio}
...

\end{document}
But when doing like this, the bibliography is the apalike style. I haven't found one that meets with what I want , so I need to modify the bibliographystyle but I don't know how

Comment: I need the references to look like this:
Tenn Raa, T., Chakraborty, D. and Small, J. 1984. “An Alternative Treatment of Secondary Products in Input-Output Analysis”. Review of Economics and Estatics. 66 (1): 88-97.

Comment: So basically you want the following changes, relative to the default output of `apalike`: (i) no parentheses around the year, (ii) quotes around the article's title, (iii) no transformation to lowercase of words in the article's title, and (iv) no use of italics for the journal name. Anything else?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a patch that you can apply to your `apalike.bst` style:

```
--- apalike.bst 2013-09-05 02:38:53.000000000 +0300
+++ napalike.bst        2013-09-05 02:59:51.000000000 +0300
@@ -121,7 +121,7 @@
 { year empty$
     { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
     { write$
-      " (" year * extra.label * ")" *
+      " " year * extra.label *
       mid.sentence 'output.state :=
     }
   if$
@@ -264,7 +264,7 @@
 FUNCTION {format.title}
 { title empty$
     { "" }
-    { title "t" change.case$ }
+    { "``" title * "''" * }
   if$
 }

@@ -294,7 +294,7 @@
 }

 FUNCTION {format.btitle}
-{ title emphasize
+{ title
 }

 FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
@@ -318,7 +318,7 @@
     { "volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
       series empty$
         'skip$
-        { " of " * series emphasize * }
+        { " of " * series * }
       if$
       "volume and number" number either.or.check
     }
@@ -430,8 +430,8 @@
 { booktitle empty$
     { "" }
     { editor empty$
-        { "In " booktitle emphasize * }
-        { "In " format.editors * ", " * booktitle emphasize * }
+        { "In " booktitle * }
+        { "In " format.editors * ", " * booktitle * }
       if$
     }
   if$
@@ -488,7 +488,7 @@
   format.title "title" output.check
   new.block
   crossref missing$
-    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
+    { journal "journal" output.check
       format.vol.num.pages output
     }
     { format.article.crossref output.nonnull }
```

I doubt that this is all you need, but the differences in the two files will give you the idea how to fix the rest.

---

The rest is information about how to apply this patch.  I'll make it brief.

A **patch** is a text file that shows what changes you need to make to one version of a file (the **original**) in order to produce a second version (the **patched** one).  What you see above was generated by the `diff` utility, which compares two files and reports the differences.

If you are using a Linux machine, or have a decent set of utilities on your Windows machine, you can directly apply the patch by:

1. Copying the original `apalike.bst` (you have to find it first) to the directory where your LaTeX source files are:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/apalike.bst apalike.bst
   ```
2. Creating a file `apalike.patch` and adding the patch above.
3. Applying the patch:

   ```
   patch < apalike.patch
   ```
4. This is all, but I'd suggest to rename the result, e.g. to `napalike.bst`, and use that in your LaTeX source; in this way, you'll remember that you have changed it.

If on the other hand you have no access to a working `patch` utility, all you need to do is to apply these changes by hand (they are not too many).  Look for `-` and `+` at the beginning of lines in the patch.  This is what you need to change.  The numbers after the `@@` denote the lines where this change has to be applied.

For example, the first change in the patch above says that, somewhere around line 121, there is a line saying `" (" year * extra.label * ")" *` (this was the minus sign), which you need to replace by `" " year * extra.label *` (this was the plus sign).

Comment: A general hint: Don't patch or otherwise apply modifications directly to a file that's part of your TeX distribution. Instead, apply the patch to a copy of the file, and save the copy under a new name.

Comment: Yes, of course, that's what I meant...  One shouldn't even have write access to the original `apalike.bst`.  But maybe I live in the linux world... :-)

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I kind of new to latex so I am not sure how to apply the patch. Do I have to create a new bst file call napalike with only this patch info? or I insert this patch inside the apalike.bst and save it as napalike.bst?

Comment: I'm adding this to the bottom of the answer.  Cheers...

Comment: Thank you again, I don´t know what I'am doing wrong. I save the patch you told in notepad++ and save it as apalike.patch. Then I downloaded  UnxUtils and open the one in the folder bin of UnxUtils. Then I wrote cd C:\Users\mvelabaron\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\bibtex\bst\apalike and finally patch < apalike.patch. Put it appeared "abnormal program termination zsh: fork failed: no such file or directory". Which step I'm missing or doing wrong
?

Comment: I also tried to copy the apalike.bst and apalike.patch to another directory. And again doing cd D:/DATA.IDB/Documents and writing patch < apalike.patch but the same error appears.

Comment: Coud "no such file or directory" mean that you have no `patch` command available?  Are you on cygwin?  BTW, it would take 2 min. to do the changes by hand...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will try to learn how to apply a patch later. For now the important was the bibliography style. Thank you.

Comment: @nickie : Thank you, I have used it. But I have a doubt.Now in my bibliography, for thesis type Ph.D it is printing like "Ph.d thesis". But I need to print it like Ph.D Thesis.for that What should I do.

Comment: @RenjthVRavi: in `apalike.bst`, function `format.thesis.type` uses `"t" change.case$` which converts the type to "title case", i.e., changes everything to lowercase apart from the first character.  You can override this by adding your type inside braces: "{Ph.D. thesis}".  Or you can patch `apalike.bst`.